# Javascript select all checkboxes in a table whose rows have a style display tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple text filter (not shown) that gives all rows in a table a display property of either "none" or "table-row". I'm trying to make my "select all" script only check the boxes that are visible, but my current code checks everything, regardless of visibility.

How do I only check the ones that are visible?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function checkAll(checktoggle)
    {
        var checkboxes = new Array(); 
        checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++)  {
            if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')   {
                checkboxes[i].checked = checktoggle;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table class="sample">
<tbody><tr><td>#</td>
<td>Topic</td>
<td>Number</td>
<td>Checkbox</td></tr>

<tr style="display: table-row;"><td>1</td>
<td>Math</td>
<td>404</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="f1" value="1"></td></tr>

<tr style="display: none;"><td>2</td>
<td>Science</td>
<td>1,283</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="f2" value="1"></td></tr>

<tr style="display: table-row;"><td>3</td>
<td>Programming</td>
<td>1,465</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="f3" value="1"></td></tr>

</table>

<a onclick="javascript:checkAll(true);" href="javascript:void();">check all</a>
<a onclick="javascript:checkAll(false);" href="javascript:void();">uncheck all</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have errors in your code. Check the tbody tag.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code which will popup what u want

```
<script>
function checkAll(checktoggle)
{
    var checkboxes = new Array(); 
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++)  {
        if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')   {
            alert(checkboxes[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.display)
            checkboxes[i].checked = checktoggle;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
function checkAll(checktoggle)
{
    var checkboxes = new Array(); 
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++)  {
        var cs = window.getComputedStyle(checkboxes[i],"");
        if (cs.display != "none" && checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')   {
            checkboxes[i].checked = checktoggle;
        }
    }
}
```

See JavaScript The Definitive Guide, Section 16.4 "Querying Computed Styles".

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is visible or not or not before check.

```
if (checkboxes[i].is(":visible")){
    checkboxes[i].checked = checktoggle;
}
```

This code will check only visibles checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the height of each row. If height > 0, the row is visible.

```
  var trElements = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var row =1, rowCount = trElements.length -1 ; row < rowCount; row++) {
    if (trElements[row].offsetHeight > 0) { // This item is visible
       if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')   {
          checkboxes[i].checked = checktoggle;
       }  
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hidden` Boolean:

```
function checkAll(checktoggle){
    var checkboxes = new Array(); 
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++)  {
        if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')   {
            if(checkboxes[i].hidden != true){ //Checks if the element is hidden
                  checkboxes[i].checked = checktoggle; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkAll(checktoggle)
{
    var tableRows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');

    for (var i=0; i < tableRows.length; i++)  {
        var tableRow = tableRows[i];
        var display = getComputedStyle(tableRow).getPropertyValue("display");
        if (display !== 'none') {
          var checkbox = tableRow.querySelector('input');
          if (checkbox.type === 'checkbox')   {
             checkbox.checked = checktoggle;
          }
        }

    }
}
```